# How can I get a Mysql result set ordered by relevancy?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have to write a simple, but till efficient and user friendly search algorithm by myself (with PHP and MySQL). So far I've created something like this with 4 different queries:

search keyword = 'something'

```
SQL condion A = ... WHERE item_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]something[[:>:]]' ...;
SQL condion B = ... WHERE item_name LIKE 'something%' ...;
SQL condion C = ...  WHERE item_name LIKE '%something%' ...;
SQL condion D = ...  WHERE tag_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]something[[:>:]]' ...;
```

which (with a little PHP) generates my list this way:

```
$list= condition A resultset THAN
$list.= condition B resultset THAN 
$list.= condition C resultset THAN
$list.= condition D resultset
```

output (ordered by search relevancy)

```
ID:4  | something
ID:54 | somethingelse
ID:2  | awholelotofsomething
ID:99 | anything (which has a tag with something)
```

(I'm collecting the item_id's of every sql query result in a php array, to prevent duplicates in the final list )

Is it possible to create this kind of search result list in one single MySQL query and still keep the proper ROW order? (With the most matching names or items at the top of the result list)

Comment: You can use `union all` and `order by`.

Comment: `MATCH() ... AGAINST()` on a `FULLTEXT` index : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html